# How to I solve the issue in add edit delete inline row in php mysql jquery?

Tags: jquery

In this code there was an issue in jquery add row does not inserting in php mysql using jquery. the formdata function does not passing the value in parameter .

Here's what I have got so far. But i am getting an issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    // Add new record button click event
    $(".add-new").click(function () {
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="crud_name" id="crud_name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="crud_email" id="crud_email"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="crud_phone_no" id="crud_phone_no"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="crud_address" id="crud_address"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="file" name="crud_image" id="crud_image" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"></td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-user-plus pe-2"></i></a>' +
            '<a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>' +
            '<a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        $("table").append(row);
        $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

    // Save new record on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function () {

        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"], input[type="file"]');
        input.each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val() && $(this).attr('type') !== 'file') {
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('crud_name',$('#crud_name').val());
        formData.append('crud_email',$('#crud_email').val());
        formData.append('crud_phone_no',$('#crud_phone_no').val());
        formData.append('crud_address',$('#crud_address').val());
        formData.append('crud_image', $('#crud_image')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $sitename . "config/ajax_add.php" ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('File upload successful:', data);
                    $("#displaymessage").html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.error('Error uploading file:', data);
                    $("#displaymessage").html(data);
                }
            });

            // You can add the code to update the UI or any other necessary action here

            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");

    });

        //Delete row on delete button click
        $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var integer = id;
            var ajaxDelUrl = '<?php echo $sitename . "config/ajax_del.php"; ?>';

            $.post(
                ajaxDelUrl, {
                    integer: integer,
                },
                function(data) {
                    $("#displaymessage").html(data);
                });
        });

        //update rec row on edit button click
        $(document).on("click", ".update", function() {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
            var crud_name = $("#crud_name").val();
            var crud_email = $("#crud_email").val();
            var crud_phone_no = $("#crud_phone_no").val();
            var crud_address = $("#crud_address").val();

            var ajaxEditUrl = '<?php echo $sitename . "config/ajax_edit.php"; ?>';


            $.post(
                ajaxEditUrl, {
                    id: id,
                    crud_name: crud_name,
                    crud_email: crud_email,
                    crud_phone_no: crud_phone_no,
                    crud_address: crud_address
                },
                function(data) {
                    $("#displaymessage").html(data);

                    console.log("Data being sent:", {
                        id: id,
                        crud_name: crud_name,
                        crud_email: crud_email,
                        crud_phone_no: crud_phone_no,
                        crud_address: crud_address
                    });

                    var newRow = $(data).find('tr[data-id="' + id + '"]');
                    $('tr[data-id="' + id + '"]').replaceWith(newRow);
                    
                    $(".add, .edit").toggle();
                    $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
                    
                }
                );


        });

        //Edit row on edit button click
        $(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
            $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(i) {
                if (i == '0') {
                    var idname = "crud_name";
                } else if (i == '1') {
                    var idname = "crud_email";
                } else if (i == '2') {
                    var idname = "crud_phone_no";
                } else if (i == '3') {
                    var idname = "crud_address";
                } else {

                }
                $(this).html('<input type="text" name="updaterec" id="' + idname + '" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
            });
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add").removeClass("add").addClass("update");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then this is an issue of the code add and edit row had some problem. Delete event function working successful. otherwise, add and edit event function does not working

What should I do?

In ajax network:
Request URL:

http://localhost/daksha/demo/admin/config/ajax_add.php

Request Method:

POST

Status Code:

200 OK

Remote Address:

[::1]:80

Referrer Policy:

strict-origin-when-cross-origin

In console.log:
File upload successful:

The data does not passing through the parameter